# Response as JSON (Retrofit + Android + PHP Slim Framework)

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit, slim

I'm using PHP Slim framework to build REST API for Android application.

I post body in app, it works well and add data to MySQL. But I have trouble in response.

**My response JSON Model is simply;**

```
{success:'yes'}
```

When I try to get response after data added, Retrofit works onFailure method. but adding data works well. I don't know where I missed. Here are my codes;

**PHP Slim Framework File**

```
$response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->getBody()->write("{success:'yes'}");
    return $response;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error": {"text": ' . $e->getMessage() . '}';
}
```

**Android Response Model**

```
public class Response_Success {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
String success;

public Response_Success(String success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public String getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(String success) {
    this.success = success;
}
```

**Interface Class**

```
public interface API_Service {
@Headers("content-type: application/json")
@POST("api/user/add")
Call<Response_Success> addFacebookUser(@Body UserFacebook userFacebook);}
```

**API Call in MainActivity**

```
API_Service service = Client.getRetrofitInstance().create(API_Service.class);

        Call<Response_Success> userFacebookCall = service.addFacebookUser(userNew);

        userFacebookCall.enqueue(new Callback<Response_Success>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Response_Success> call, Response<Response_Success> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response.body().getSuccess(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response_Success> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "was wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

*Debug mode in android studio; I get MaltFormedJsonException, but I added that exception in try catch.*

Comment: You can do - `return $response->withJson(array('success' => 'yes'));` (https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html#returning-json)

Comment: Good alternative, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Json response

> {success:'yes'}

is invalid. The key and (string) value must be in double quotes.

Either make sure your response is in double quotes:

> {"success":"yes"}

or try this instead:

```
$response = array();
$response["success"] = "yes";
echo json_encode($response);
```

Note: you can check to see if any JSON string is valid at: 
https://jsonlint.com/
Or
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/